# Binary Encoder Circuit

Tags: encoder, diy, binary

How exactly would I go from 7 output lines to 127 outputs. Since you can encoder a value of 127 with 7 lines I would imagine this should be possible.

Comment: You are looking for a decoder. There are 128 possible combinations. The first is IN[6:0]=0000000, the decoder output is an AND gate with 7 inputs, all inverted. The second is 0000001, and it is an AND gate will all but the lowest bit inverted. Repeat that 128 times with each binary code and you will have a 7->128 binary decoder. There is often an additional input to enable/disable all outputs and make a demultiplexer.

Comment: Do you have an example of this?

Comment: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/74ac11138.pdf This datasheet has examples of how to go from a few address lines to many output lines. You should be able to extend this method to handle more inputs/outputs.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is called a decoder.  Although I don't believe there is a 7 to 128 decoder, there are 3 to 8 decoders (maybe even 4 to 16). If you use 3 to 8 decoders, you will need 16 of them. If you use 4 to 16 decoders, you will only need 8.  Follow the manufacturer's instructions on **how to cascade** them, and you will have your 7 to 128 decoder.